# Docker and WSGI with a Python Pyramid app?

Tags: python, docker, pyramid

I am looking at two articles on how to Dockerize a Pyramid app. I am not that familiar with Python, but I am fairly certain with a Pyramid app you need to use WSGI.

This article uses WSGI:
https://medium.com/@greut/minimal-python-deployment-on-docker-with-uwsgi-bc5aa89b3d35

This one just runs the python executable directly:
https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-pyramid-application

It seems unlikely to me that you can run python directly and not incorporate WSGI, can anyone provide an explanation for why the runnable.com article's docker solution would work?

Comment: In the `hello_world.py` that they reference, there is a wsgi server being created with `app = config.make_wsgi_app(); server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)`

Comment: @C.Nivs ah thanks, that makes sense, probably can add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the scripts in the [second link](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-pyramid-application):

```py
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

~snip~

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('hello', '/')
    config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app() # The wsgi server is configured here
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app) # and here
```

[This](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/hello_world.html) contains an explanation of why the wsgi server is built in the `if __name__=="__main__"` block